# Configuration for salt-minion in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack

I have an environment of four VMs in Vagrant. I'm using SaltStack to automate installation and configuration of an application. One VM is a salt-master and three are salt-minions. Currently, when I install one of the minions from zero, I have to SSH to this VM, install Salt and set grains for this minion. I would like to specify these configurations in a file that will be passed to a VM during the initialization so that I won't need to SSH into a minion VM.

So here's section from `Vagrantfile` for one of the minions:

```
  config.vm.define "loadbalancer" do |loadbalancer|
    loadbalancer.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    loadbalancer.vm.hostname = "loadbalancer"

    loadbalancer.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
      salt.minion_config = "salt/minion"
    end

  end
```

And `salt/minion` file looks like this:

```
master: 192.168.10.10
grains:
  roles:
    - load-balancing
```

Am using the right approach for this task? When I run `vagrant up` with this set-up, I get this error output:

```
 *  INFO: Running install_ubuntu_check_services()
 *  INFO: Running install_ubuntu_restart_daemons()
salt-minion start/running, process 9632
 *  INFO: Running daemons_running()
 * ERROR: salt-minion was not found running
 * ERROR: Failed to run daemons_running()!!!
 * ERROR: salt-minion was not found running. Pass '-D' to bootstrap-salt.sh when bootstrapping for additional debugging information...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the configuration is correct. The reason why I got this error is that the salt-master had an old key for this minion. When I removed a key of a minion and recreated the minion again, I get it working as expected.